# Rails - How do I 'merge' or append a value to an array within the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to pass an array in the URL, which is working fine, but I'd like to know how I can then insert or remove certain values?

For example, I have a link that looks like:

```
http://localhost:3000/pins?genre_ids[]=1,2,3
```

I would like to build a set of links that can insert or remove numbers from this URL array.

At the moment, each link I have simply changes the genre_ids[] value completely, where as I'd like to add to it, or take away as needed. This is my code to build the link...

```
<%= link_to genre[0].title, pins_path( params.merge({ :genre_ids => [genre[0].id] }) ) %>
```

I think what I'm after is something like `params.merge()` but for the value of `params[:genre_ids]`

I hope you can understand what I mean? If the current URL reads `/pins?genre_ids[]=1,2,3` I'd like it so that each link I build includes this current link, with the addition of another number into this array, so that it would look like `/pins?genre_ids[]=1,2,3,4`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm from a CF background, so I'm still trying to get my head around Ruby and Rails. I am using Rails 4 with Ruby 2.

Thanks,
Michael.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are overwriting your `genre_ids` array.  You need to combine the two arrays, which you can do using the `+` operator:

`params[:genre_ids] + [genre[0].id]`

I think this will do the trick:

```
<%= link_to genre[0].title, pins_path( params.merge({ :genre_ids => (params[:genre_ids] + [genre[0].id]) }) ) %>
```

However, it should be noted that you can end up with duplicate array object values.  You may want to consider using the "union" operator `|`.

Example:

```
first = [1,2,3,4]
second = [3,4,5,6]
first + second #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6]
first | second #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

So maybe your link should be:

```
<%= link_to genre[0].title, pins_path( params.merge({ :genre_ids => (params[:genre_ids] | [genre[0].id]) }) ) %>
```

Comment: That's the ticket! I initially tried this without the surrounding brackets, so I got an error. I felt it would be something like this, so thanks for the correct syntax.

Comment: Brilliant addition regarding the union operator. Thanks again!

Comment: @johnnycakes --- what about in the case where :genre_ids has not yet been set. I am getting urls generated /pins&genre_ids=true

I saw other examples where people recommended using params.slice[:genre_ids] then merging

Comment: Any idea how I'd go about doing the same in Rails 5?