# Get from the link_to an array of values Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="menu">
    <% @dogs.each do |dog| %>
      <%= link_to dog[:name], params.merge(dog_id: dog[:id], page: nil), class: 'item' %>        
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm working on a project, I need to add to the params by clicking the id array with one key. Tried like this, but leads to unexpected results, I ask for help.

```
<i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="menu">
    <% @dogs.each do |dog| %>
      <%= link_to dog[:name], params.merge(dog_id: params.push(dog[:id]), page: nil), class: 'item' %>        
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I understand what should look like this

```
<%= link_to dog[:name], params.merge(dog_id: [0, 1, 4, 6], page: nil), class: 'item' %>
```

But I can not realize. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean, could you explain?

Comment: what are the unexpected results?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, but  If `@dogs` is an ActiveRecord array of dog objects then you would have to use `dog.name` instead of `dog[:name]`

Comment: Sorry, I found the answer, I did not look long enough ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833039/rails-how-do-i-merge-or-append-a-value-to-an-array-within-the-url